# Combining bokeh formatter and prefixed.Float

Tags: python, bokeh

I would like to format my axis tickers with `prefixed.Float` output.
I want it to be formatted as I would do when creating a string: `f'{prefixed.Float(value):.2h}'`

There is the `FuncTickFormatter` in bokeh but that allows me to embed JS, not a python function. `PrintfTickFormatter(format="%4.1e")` comes close to what I want but still uses the ordinary printf formatting string and can't use `prefixed.Float`.

How can I give the bokeh axis formatter a formatter which calls `prefixed.Float`?

Comment: Does [NumeralTickFormatter(format="0.0 a")](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.NumeralTickFormatter) the job for you?

Comment: @mosc9575 not really. it is completely wrong, m != M for SI prefixes

Answer (score 0):

> How can I give the bokeh axis formatter a formatter which calls prefixed.Float?

You can't. Tick Formatting is done entirely on the JavaScript side, so using Python tools to do the work is a non-starter. Your best option is implement a `FuncTickFormatter` that performs whatever custom formatting you require in JavaScript.

Your *only* option to use `prefixed` would be to use a [`FixedTicker`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling/plots.html#tick-locations) to specify a single, static set of tick locations (so no change if zoomed in or out) and then to set the axis property `major_label_overrides` to map those fixed tick locations to tick labels strings for those locations that you generated in Python.